# How can use Perl to assign a task in Outlook to some person?

Tags: perl, outlook

How can I assign a task in Outlook to some person as sending a mail using Perl or using any command in unix?

Answer (score 2):

See [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [POI-HSMF](http://poi.apache.org/hsmf/index.html). You can use [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/~patl/Inline-Java-0.52/) to access POI.